# CSS Modules Inheritance Image Height 100% Issue

Tags: html, css, image, styling, css-modules

For some reason, my images are being vertically distorted and I can't figure out as to why (See image below).

[image: distorted images][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOJeE.jpg)

[image: inspect element on distorted images][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ICo6.jpg)

[image: inspect element on distorted images][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr6mb.jpg)

Long story short what I've done is moved all my single-page-app (SPA) app code/styles and created a server-side rendered codebase. I haven't changed any of the styles or tweaked anything, yet for some reason it's distorting. This is the working styles / code from the SPA app.

[image: working HTML & CSS][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZJps.jpg)

The only hack that seems to do much of anything is when I take out the

```
`height:100%;`
```

on the images, but this has a negative effect with filling out the images which is what I'm wanting.

[image: css hack fix][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFdxi.jpg)

I'm using CSS Modules and have some idea that it could be related to some inheritance issues that I'm unaware of. Thanks in advance, this bug is really been driving me crazy.

I've created a fiddle that represents the working code from the SPA. https://jsfiddle.net/0L0rdk6y/

Comment: if you can share code example it will help us

Comment: Hi @AdnanAkram Please find fiddle. For your reference this is the working html/css, I'm unable to build a fiddle to represent the non-working one. https://jsfiddle.net/0L0rdk6y/

Comment: Can you share link where i can see actual issue as in fiddle it work perfectly fine

Comment: (This is not a solution imho) Have you tried to use the object-fit property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @Andy I think issue is we need to show 4 blocks in one row

Comment: Oh, now I got it, thanks! In that case, I think that there are always 8 blocks in a row(you can see it even from the fiddle expanding via drag and drop the window with the blocks). And this is because the class .item has a property flex-basis: calc(100/8)

Comment: For 'always' I mean for big screens

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by adding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

in my render method when returning server side html

Example is 
    return 
        `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                ${renderBaseMeta()}
                ${helmet.title.toString()}
                ${helmet.meta.toString()}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="root">${content}</div>
                <script>
                    window.INITIAL_STATE = ${serialize(store.getState())}
                </script>
                <script src="bundle.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>`
;